# How to sync my customer data to quickbooks through web connector?

Tags: web-services, quickbooks

I have Quickbooks Desktop Enterprise 18.0. I already created connection using  qwc file through web connector.when I click Update selected option from web connector the result says okay. But If I include customer data in web service and click Update selected it shows error in status bar i.e Description:
Error message received from application via getLastError(): Error!.

I pasted code below Please review it and Guide if there anything wrong. Thank you.

```
public ArrayList buildRequest() {
        string strRequestXML ="";
        XmlDocument inputXMLDoc = null;

        // CustomerQuery
        inputXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0",null, null));

inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("qbxml", "version=\"4.0\""));

        XmlElement qbXML = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBXML");
        inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(qbXML);
        XmlElement qbXMLMsgsRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBXMLMsgsRq");
        qbXML.AppendChild(qbXMLMsgsRq);
        qbXMLMsgsRq.SetAttribute("onError", "stopOnError");
        XmlElement CustomerAddRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerAddRq");
        qbXML.AppendChild(CustomerAddRq);
        qbXMLMsgsRq.SetAttribute("requestID", "1");
        XmlElement CustomerAdd = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerAdd");
        CustomerAddRq.AppendChild(CustomerAdd);
        XmlElement Name = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("Name");
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(Name);
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(Name).InnerText = "Naga";
        XmlElement FirstName = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("FirstName");
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(FirstName);
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(Name).InnerText = "Nagarajan";

        XmlElement MiddleName = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("MiddleName");
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(MiddleName);
        XmlElement LastName = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("LastName");
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(LastName);
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(Name).InnerText = "Varatharajan";

        XmlElement BillAddress = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("BillAddress");
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(BillAddress);


        XmlElement Addr1 = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("Addr1");
        BillAddress.AppendChild(Addr1);
        BillAddress.AppendChild(Addr1).InnerText = "33/33 st";


        XmlElement City = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("City");
        BillAddress.AppendChild(City);
        BillAddress.AppendChild(City).InnerText = "Chennai";
        XmlElement State = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("State");
        BillAddress.AppendChild(State);
        BillAddress.AppendChild(State).InnerText = "TN";
        XmlElement Phone = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("Phone");
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(Phone);
        CustomerAdd.AppendChild(Phone).InnerText = "4545455";
        //XmlElement customerQueryRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerQueryRq");
        //qbXMLMsgsRq.AppendChild(customerQueryRq);
        //customerQueryRq.SetAttribute("requestID", "1");
        //  XmlElement maxReturned=inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("MaxReturned");
        //  customerQueryRq.AppendChild(maxReturned).InnerText="1";

        strRequestXML = inputXMLDoc.OuterXml;
        req.Add(strRequestXML);
}
```

Comment: Post your Web Connector logs in VERBOSE mode, or some other log showing the actual qbXML request sent to QuickBooks, and the actual qbXML response you got back from QuickBooks. Without that, you won't be able to troubleshoot.

Comment: You can get the logs @KeithPalmerJr. is requesting by clicking the "View Log" button at the top of Quickbooks Web Connector.

Comment: @NagarajanVaratharajan I'm also working on same thing and posted my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52608855/how-to-connect-quickbooks-desktop-using-web-connector here, if you can help me and answer to the questions it would be great. Thanks!