# How to connect QuickBooks Desktop using Web Connector?

Tags: c#, webforms, asmx, quickbooks

I'm trying to develop a simple webform application to create/edit invoice from a .aspx page and want to sync QB Desktop & MS SQL database using web connector & .ASMX web service (**2 way sync: QBD -> web app & web app > QBD**).

Here is a what I did:

1. I've setup [QB Desktop US version 19 (latest) and Web connector](https://community.intuit.com/articles/1558144-set-up-quickbooks-web-connector)
2. Added an application via adding .QWC file (I'm using this default .qwc file without any changes, not sure even how can I make it!!)

Step 1 & 2, are done but looking for proper solution to start with the development part. I've referred some other StackOverflow questions and found [this sample](https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK13_Samples/tree/master/qbdt/c-sharp) but not sure which project and version I've to choose from both of them. I'm finding some good sample applications which connects to QB Desktop & Web applications using `Interop.QBFC13`

I really don't have idea how web connector works and sync with my web app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using this default .qwc file without any changes, not sure even how can I make it!!

This ^^^ *will not work*. Ever. There is no "default" `.QWC` file -- it is specific *to your application* and if you're using someone else's it's guaranteed not to work.

Create your own `.QWC` file. Example template:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBWCXML>
    <AppName>QuickBooks Integrator</AppName>
    <AppID></AppID>
    <AppURL>https://example.com/quickbooks/server.php</AppURL>
    <AppDescription></AppDescription>
    <AppSupport>https://example.com/quickbooks/support.php</AppSupport>
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
    <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4FCC-B1FF-967DE1813D20}</FileID>
    <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
    <Scheduler>
        <RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
    </Scheduler>
    <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
```

Fields:

- `<AppName>` This is displayed to the user in the Web Connector GUI
- `<AppID></AppID>` Leave it blank
- `<AppSupport>...</AppSupport>` Must contain a valid URL to a valid page which returns a 200 OK HTTP response when visited. Users who have technical problems will be directed here.
- `<AppURL>...</AppURL>` Must contain a valid URL to your SOAP server, `https://...` if it's remote, `http://localhost/...` if it's local.
- `<UserName>...</UserName>` This will match the username your SOAP server understands for authentication
- `<FileID>...</FileID>` You can make this up as long as it follows the GUID format (uppercase HEX chars only!): `{6904A826-7368-11DC-8317-F7AD55D89593}`. It has something to do with DataExt elements; most simple integrations can just make this up.
- `<OwnerID>...</OwnerID>` Same as above
- `<QBType>...</QBType>` Specifies the type of Quickbooks you want to connect to with the web connector (ie “QBFS” or “QBPOS”)
- `<Scheduler>...</Scheduler>` This is an optional element, use this to schedule the Web Connector to run every so often automatically
- `<IsReadOnly>...</IsReadOnly>` Leave this set to `false`, setting it to `true` will not work.

Did you read the 100+ page PDF that documents exactly how the Web Connector works and what you need to implement? Link:

- [QuickBooks Web Connector Programmer's Guide PDF](https://developer-static.intuit.com/qbSDK-current/doc/PDF/QBWC_proguide.pdf)

What have you tried to implement so far?

Comment: How can we check 64 bit SDK support for QB Desktop?

Comment: I've checked https://help.developer.intuit.com/s/question/0D5G000004Dk7E3KAJ/our-app-requires-64bit-report-viewer-needs-2gb-ram-how-can-we-use-the-qbfc-sdk-with-a-64bit-app-when-will-the-intuit-developers-be-building-a-64bit-version  here but no update since 1 year.

Comment: If you're integrating via the Web Connector, then _you do not need to use the SDK_. So this shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: So you mean we can use `qbXML` instead `QBFC` from this https://github.com/IntuitDeveloper/QBXML_SDK13_Samples/tree/master/qbdt/c-sharp github projects?

Comment: The Web Connector does _not_ use QBFC. Use qbXML if you're using the Web Connector.

Comment: It means if we use web connector with qbXML and it'll support in 64-bit, right?

Comment: Yes. It's a SOAP web service, so it doesn't even matter if it's 32 bit or 64 bit of any-random-bit since it's all text over the wire anyway.